Kicad 8.0 Bus Management
I've come across a situation in Kicad 8.0 where I'm not entirely sure how to get what I want from the Schematic. I have a design that calls for 4 channels, each of which shares a common data bus, update signal, and has an individual write signal. All of these enter the sheet grouped into a single bus. 
The picture below hopefully helps to clarify.

So my question is can I link these up, without having to do each bit in the 17-channel data bus? This would work, but that's going to be 18 x 4 x 2 labels to do to build all 4 buses that way. What I want to be able to do is pull the vectors out of the buses and join them together like I would with a wire. So in the image above, a line joins FSM.D[0..17] and CH1.D[0..17]. 
I realise I probably could get around the problem, by splitting the data bus out by itself both entering the sheet and entering the sub sheets, but I'd like to do it in the busses above. That way I have one bus for all the control signals coming from the FPGA for the FSM, and then one bus per channel.

It's worth noting that there are a number of bugs currently with the interaction between buses and subsheets. I don't think this is a case of that, but be aware that there are known bugs with what you're trying to do. (And it might be worth a feature request, if there's no good way to do it.)
